# AWS Step Function: Function .length() returned error in variable field in Choice state

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I have a Choice state in AWS Step Function that would compare an array's length from Input and make decision to go next state.

However, the `length()` function, to get the array's length, returned an error:

> {
> "error": "States.Runtime",
> "cause": "An error occurred while executing the state    'CheckItemsCountState' (entered at the event id #18). Invalid path '$.Metadata[2].Items.length()': The choice state's condition path references an invalid value."
>
> }

The Choice state's definition is as below:

```
     "CheckItemsCountState":{  
         "Type": "Choice",
         "InputPath": "$",
         "OutputPath": "$",
         "Default": "NoItemsState",
         "Choices":[  
            {  
               "Variable": "$.Metadata[2].Items.length()",
               "NumericGreaterThan": 0,
               "Next": "ProcessState"
            }
         ]
      },
```

The state is connected some other state that returns a JSON. The JSON is as below:

```
{
  "Metadata": [
    {
      "foo": "name"
    },
    {
      "Status": "COMPLETED"
    },
    {
      "Items": []
    }
  ]
}
```

So I was trying to get the length of `Items` in `Metadata[2]` and make comparison if the value is greater than 0.

I have tried to validate the JsonPath `$.Metadata[2].Items.length()` in this [website](http://jsonpath.herokuapp.com) and it returns 0.

I am not sure if I've missed anything. I couldn't find any information in AWS Step Function's docs or example on using function in jsonpath.

I would appreciate for any help. Thank you!

Comment: just to understand the question correctly, the JSON containing "MetaData" and "Items" is the exact json copied from aws step function console?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Step Functions do not allow you to use functions to get values. From the [Choice Rules documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-choice-state.html#amazon-states-language-choice-state-rules):

> For each of these operators, the corresponding value must be of the
>   appropriate type: string, number, Boolean, or timestamp.

To do what you're asking, you would need to get the array length in the previous function and return it as part of the output.

```
{
  "Metadata": [
    {
      "foo": "name"
    },
    {
      "Status": "COMPLETED"
    },
    {
      "Items": [],
      "ItemsCount": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Then in the Step Function Choice step:

```
"CheckItemsCountState":{  
    "Type": "Choice",
    "InputPath": "$",
    "OutputPath": "$",
    "Default": "NoItemsState",
    "Choices":[  
        {  
            "Variable": "$.Metadata[2].ItemsCount",
            "NumericGreaterThan": 0,
            "Next": "ProcessState"
        }
    ]
},
```

Comment: This technique is working. I was hoping that functions in JSONPath workable in Step Function. By the way, thank you for taking your time answering my question.

Answer (score 11):

One possible way is to check the zero index, if you just want to check it's a non-empty array.

You can do something like this

```
"CheckItemsCountState":{  
     "Type": "Choice",
     "InputPath": "$",
     "OutputPath": "$",
     "Default": "NoItemsState",
     "Choices":[
       {
         "And": [
           {
            "Variable": "$.Metadata[2].Items",
            "IsPresent": true
           },
           {
             "Variable": "$.Metadata[2].Items[0]",
             "IsPresent": true
           }
         ],
        "Next": "ProcessState"
       }
     ]
  }
```

The other way is what's mentioned in the accepted answer, to set the count in the previous function.

Answer (score 5):

AWS Step Functions added 14 Intrinsic Functions, including `States.ArrayLength`  that will address this question:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions.html#asl-intrsc-func-arrays

For example, given the following input array:

```
{
   "inputArray": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
}
```

You can use States.ArrayLength to return the length of inputArray:

```
"length.$": "States.ArrayLength($.inputArray)"
```

In this example, States.ArrayLength would return the following JSON object that represents the array length:

```
{ "length": 9 }
```

Comment: This will not work for Choice state.